# Validación de propiedades con DataAnnotations heredadas de una clase base

Tags: c#, herencia

He creado una solución común con un proyecto que contiene una clase base con propiedades DataAnnotations:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Common.DataContracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class DatosPersona
    {
        [DataMember]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'NroDocum' no es válida.")]
        public string NroDocum { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{0,8})?$", ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'SubDocum' no es válida.")]
        public int? SubDocum { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'Apellidos' no es válida.")]
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'ApellidosMas' no es válida.")]
        public string ApellidosMas { get; set; }
      }
}
```

Estos datos se validan en una clase abstracta definida en otro proyecto de la solución común:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Common.DomainService.Mappers
{
    public abstract class CommonFieldsValidator
    {
        public virtual List<ValidationResult> ValidationErrors { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valida los campos del dto informado T según sus atributos ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool FieldsValidate<T>(T ObjDataFields) 
        {
            return Validator.TryValidateObject(ObjDataFields, new ValidationContext(ObjDataFields), ValidationErrors, true);
        }

        public CommonFieldsValidator()
        {
            ValidationErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

En un servicio web tengo una clase hija que hereda de la clase base e implementa nuevas propiedades:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Common.DataContracts;

namespace DataContracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class DataContractPersona : DatosPersona
    {
        [DataMember]
        [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'CodDocum' no es válida.")]
        public string CodDocum { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{0,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "El formato del campo 'Idioma' no es válido.")]
        public int? Idioma { get; set; }
    }
}
```

El caso es que me valida correctamente las propiedades con DataAnnotations de mi clase hija pero no las propiedades con DataAnnotations de la clase base y no entiendo porqué.

Me he fijado que las etiquetas [DataContract] y [DataMember] no se muestran al ir a la definición desde la solución del servicio web:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Common.DataContracts
{
    public class DatosPersona
    {
        public DatosPersona();

        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'Apellidos' no es válida.")]
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del campo 'ApellidosMas' no es válida.")]
        public string ApellidosMas { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sólo no las valida? el resto de la Metadata llega a la clase hija?

Comment: Todos los metadatos llegan a la clase hija. Respecto a los label que no se mostraban era porque estaba en tiempo de ejecución.

--

Ya está resuelto. Al parecer la referencia no se estaba serializando correctamente. 

He vuelto a limpiar la solución padre, recompilar, borrar la referencia a ésta y volver a agregarla.

Ahora funciona correctamente.

Comment: Me alegro que hayas solucionado tu problema, porfavor, agrega una respuesta a la pregunta con la solución. De modo que si alguien lo necesita en un futuro pueda encontrarlo

Comment: Actualmente no se usa las DataAnnotations, lo que se usa es una librería que facilita esto https://fluentvalidation.net/ espero que te sirva...

Comment: Por favor @Mario agrega la respuesta y márcala como aceptada para mantener la buena salud del sitio :D